# boost::filesystem::path.parent_path() and whitespace

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

I want to check a path from a users input. The input must provide a path of a file which does not exist. Further, if the input also provides directories, these directories must exists.

Example inputs:

`/existent_dir_a/existent_dir_b/existent_file.bin` <-- false

`/existent_dir_a/existent_dir_b/non_existent_file.bin` <-- ok

`/non_existent_dir_a/non_existent_file.bin` <-- false

`non_existent_file.bin` <-- ok

`existent_file.bin` <-- false

The code below shows an example. I hope that it archieve my goal but I have still one question.

How can I get rid of `output.parent_path().string().size() != 0` as it seems a bit ugly to me?

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <exception>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

int main(int ac, char ** av)
{
  fs::path output(av[1]);

  std::cout << output << std::endl;

  std::cout << output.parent_path() << std::endl;

  if (fs::exists(output))
  {
    std::string msg = output.string() + " already exists";

    throw std::invalid_argument(msg);
  }

  if ( output.parent_path().string().size() != 0 &&
       !fs::exists(output.parent_path()) )
  {
    std::string msg = output.parent_path().string() + " is not a directory";

    throw std::invalid_argument(msg);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `!output.parent_path().empty()`